# Use variable in wmic command inside for loop in Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am unable to get this query to work:

```
set APPNAME="App Name"

for /f "skip=1delims= " %%t in ('wmic product where "name=%APPNAME%" get IdentifyingNumber') do set "guid=%%t"& goto printguid
:printguid
    echo %guid%
```

I am getting "Invalid alias verb" error. I am not able to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Your variable `APPNAME` contains quotes, change your first line to `set "APPNAME=App Name"`, else you add the quotes also into the where clause, like `... where "name="AppName"" ...`

Comment: `wmic product where name="%APPNAME%" get IdentifyingNumber` or`wmic product where "name="%APPNAME%"" get IdentifyingNumber` where `%APPNAME%`should *not* have quotes, or `wmic product where "name=%APPNAME%" get IdentifyingNumber`, where `%APPNAME%` *should* have quotes. (recommendation: *never* define a variable with surrounding quotes; quote them when used (if necessary) - much easier to spot any errors in code)

Comment: @AbhayGupta, please note that the method used in the answer you have currently accepted, had you read my answer, uses WMI to enumerate Win32_Product. This is dangerous, and the official recommendation is that you do not do it. Also, and feel free to try it, `WMIC.exe`, even without the long enumeration of your Microsoft Installer products, will still take longer than running the `reg.exe` method too. Whilst you're free to select the answer you prefer, it is really important that future readers are aware that the accepted answer is not always the best, safest, or quickest way to perform a task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark about `WMIC` : Don't forget that the output of WMIC is unicode !

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another `FOR /F` loop. This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`)

So i tested this batch with `"APPNAME=VirtualDJ 8"` on my side and it works 5/5

```bat
@echo off
Title Get IdentifyingNumber from Application using WMIC
set "APPNAME=VirtualDJ 8"
set "GUID="
echo    Please Wait a while ... Getting IdentifyingNumber from this Application "%APPNAME%"
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic product where name="%APPNAME%" get IdentifyingNumber"') do (
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined GUID set "GUID=%%~nb"
)
cls
echo The Application "%AppName%" has a Guid like this one : "%GUID%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

When Win32_Product is enumerated, it actually performs a full status check on each product. This not only affects your script time, but can also mean that repairs/modifications are made too. The official recommendation is therefore not to use Win32_Product, *(for which `Product` is a [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) alias)*

I would therefore recommend, and it should be much quicker, that you parse the registry instead, for your information.

The following example searches all data values under the key branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products`, and uses the last leaf of the matched subkey, to recreate the GUID string you require, *(same string just ordered differently)*:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "AppName=App Name"
Set "FindCmd=%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe"
Set "RegExe=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
Set "RegKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products"
Set "{}="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%RegExe%" Query "%RegKey%" /S /F "%AppName%" /D /E
 2^> NUL ^| "%FindCmd%" /I "%RegKey:*\=%"^"') Do @Set "{}=%%~nxG"
If Not Defined {} GoTo :EOF
Set GUID={%{}:~7,1%%{}:~6,1%%{}:~5,1%%{}:~4,1%%{}:~3,1%%{}:~2,1%%{}:~1,1%^
%{}:~,1%-%{}:~11,1%%{}:~10,1%%{}:~9,1%%{}:~8,1%-%{}:~15,1%%{}:~14,1%%{}:~13,1%^
%{}:~12,1%-%{}:~-15,1%%{}:~-16,1%%{}:~-13,1%%{}:~-14,1%-%{}:~-11,1%%{}:~-12,1%^
%{}:~-9,1%%{}:~-10,1%%{}:~-7,1%%{}:~-8,1%%{}:~-5,1%%{}:~-6,1%%{}:~-3,1%^
%{}:~-4,1%%{}:~-1%%{}:~-2,1%}
Set GUID & Pause
```

Just change line `2` to replace your `App Name` placeholder with your actual Product Name. The last line is optional and was included just to ensure that the result matches your expectation.